# Has anyone translated activerecord into other languages such as french for use with tolk/i18n gem?

Tags: translation, rails-i18n

eg, English translation:

```
en-US:
  number:
    # Used in number_with_delimiter()
    # These are also the defaults for 'currency', 'percentage', 'precision', and 'human'
    format:
      # Sets the separator between the units, for more precision (e.g. 1.0 / 2.0 == 0.5)
      separator: "." 
      # Delimets thousands (e.g. 1,000,000 is a million) (always in groups of three)
      delimiter: "," 
      # Number of decimals, behind the separator (1 with a precision of 2 gives: 1.00)
      precision: 3

    # Used in number_to_currency()
    currency:
      format:
        # Where is the currency sign? %u is the currency unit, %n the number (default: $5.00)
        format: "%u%n" 
        unit: "$" 
        # These three are to override number.format and are optional
        separator: "." 
        delimiter: "," 
        precision: 2

    # Used in number_to_percentage()
    percentage:
      format:
        # These three are to override number.format and are optional
        # separator: 
        delimiter: "" 
        # precision: 

    # Used in number_to_precision()
    precision:
      format:
        # These three are to override number.format and are optional
        # separator:
        delimiter: "" 
        # precision:

    # Used in number_to_human_size()
    human:
      format:
        # These three are to override number.format and are optional
        # separator: 
        delimiter: "" 
        precision: 1

  # Used in distance_of_time_in_words(), distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(), time_ago_in_words()
  datetime:
    distance_in_words:
      half_a_minute: "half a minute" 
      less_than_x_seconds:
        one:  "less than 1 second" 
        many: "less than {{count}} seconds" 
      x_seconds:
        one:  "1 second" 
        many: "{{count}} seconds" 
      less_than_x_minutes:
        one:  "less than a minute" 
        many: "less than {{count}} minutes" 
      x_minutes:
        one:  "1 minute" 
        many: "{{count}} minutes" 
      about_x_hours:
        one:  "about 1 hour" 
        many: "about {{count}} hours" 
      x_days:
        one:  "1 day" 
        many: "{{count}} days" 
      about_x_months:
        one:  "about 1 month" 
        many: "about {{count}} months" 
      x_months:
        one:  "1 month" 
        many: "{{count}} months" 
      about_x_years:
        one:  "about 1 year" 
        many: "about {{count}} years" 
      over_x_years:
        one:  "over 1 year" 
        many: "over {{count}} years" 

  activerecord:
    errors:
      template:
        header:
          one:   "1 error prohibited this {{model}} from being saved" 
          other:  "{{count}} errors prohibited this {{model}} from being saved" 
        # The variable :count is also available
        body: "There were problems with the following fields:"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locales are in the github repo for i18n under rails-i18n / rails / locale @
http://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n